# Understand why rank() over doesn't fit to don't select duplicates rows

Tags: window-functions, redshift, rank

I would like to understand why I have different results

I have a table called active_transfert where I log image transfert

```
user_id | image_id | created_at
--------|----------|-----------
1       |1         |2014-07-10
1       |2         |2015-01-21
2       |1         |2015-05-23
3       |1         |2016-07-22
4       |6         |2017-06-01
4       |6         |2014-08-22
```

I would like to return unique user_id per image_id.

```
SELECT user_id,
       image_id
FROM active_transfert
GROUP BY user_id,
         image_id; --50


SELECT user_id,
       image_id
FROM
  (SELECT user_id,
          image_id,
          rank() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, image_id
                       ORDER BY created_at DESC) AS i_ranked
   FROM active_transfert) AS i
WHERE i.i_ranked = 1; -- 53
```

I run those queries against Redshift. Why my second query doesn't prevent duplicated records (same user_id and image_id)?

Expected result :

```
user_id | image_id |
--------|----------|
1       |1         |
1       |2         |
2       |1         |
3       |1         |
4       |6         |
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`RANK()` is a deterministic function, meaning that duplicates will be labelled with the same rank value. The outputs of your queries suggests to me that there are multiple records with the same `user_id` and `image_id` that also have the same `created_at` value. These records will all return with the same `RANK()` value.

If you run your inner query, you will see these duplicates where all three attributes are the same. If the `created_date` is also the largest value for that combination of `user_id` and `image_id` they will all have the `RANK()` value of 1.

To get your desired output, you should instead be using `ROW_NUMBER()`. This is a non deterministic function when the parameters in the `OVER` clause do not uniquely determine the rows, which is true in this case. This will assign a unique result to every row, but as your `RANK()` query provided duplicates it will assign each of these rows a unique value at random.

Your second query using `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT user_id,
       image_id
FROM
  (SELECT user_id,
          image_id,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, image_id
                       ORDER BY created_at DESC) AS i_ranked
   FROM active_downloads) AS i
WHERE i.i_ranked = 1;
```

Comment: How do i select the row with max`i_ranked` value, I cannot use `WHERE i.i_ranked = MAX(i.i_ranked)` since its not allowed.